# Is there an identity for cos(ab)?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that there is a trig identity for $\cos(a+b)$ and an identity for $\cos(2a)$, but is there an identity for $\cos(ab)$?

$\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b -\sin a \sin b$

$\cos(2a)=\cos^2a-\sin^2a$

$\cos(ab)=?$

Comment: Are $a,b$ arbitrary, or are you assuming that $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ is an integer?

Comment: Might not be too helpful, but you can expand $\cos((a+b)^2)$ and use the identities you have above to get a formula for $\cos(ab)$.

Comment: @Clayton .. but.. do we have any formula for $\cos(a^2)$??

Comment: @Berci Well, if $a$ is $2$, we have $cos^22-sin^22$

Comment: @ColeJohnson There is a formula if $a$ is any integer.

Comment: @Berci Try this out (particularly my answer):  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640435/is-there-no-formula-for-cosx2

Comment: Using $$ab = \dfrac{1}{4}[(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2],$$ and the formulas for $\cos(x-y),\cos(z/2)$, it is sufficient to consider the case of $\cos(t^2)$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640435.

Answer (score 18):

No, and there's a precise reason.

First, the geometric definition of $\cos$ talks about angles, and the product of two angles doesn't make sense.

Moreover, when you view the cosine as an exponential complex function, as you know $$\cos{x}= \frac{ e^{i x} + e^{-i x}}{2} $$ you can see that the identities you quoted come from properties of powers, such as $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$ or $e^{2a} = (e^a)^2$

Since there's no significant formula for $e^{ab}$, there isn't one for the $\cos$ function too.

Comment: Well, there is one: $$e^{ab}=(e^a)^b=(e^b)^a$$

Comment: Although similar, the formula from $(e^a)^2$ comes from the fact it is $e^a e^a$. As pointed out by someone else in the comments, if $b$ is an integer then a formula does exist (or $a$)

Comment: Dimensionally speaking, an angle is a _dimensionless_ quantity; there's no reason that the product of two angles necessarily fails to make sense.  (The second half of your answer actually illustrates why this is necessary, because you can't exponentiate dimensioned quantities; if angles _weren't_ dimensionless, then the expression $e^{ix}$ wouldn't make dimensional sense.

Comment: I meant it doesn't have a geometric sense, at least not an immediate one. You can't derive a general formula from geometry, that's what I meant.
You're right though

Comment: A very interesting “answer” that shows (together with @Berci’s comment) how author’s original thought became ruined when expressed with symbols. $e^{ab} = (e^a)^b$ is indeed a very “significant” identity **when *b* is a rational number.**

Answer (score 10):

If $a$ is an integer and $b$ is an angle,

$$\cos(ab) = T_a(\cos b)$$

where $T_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: It does not have to be an integer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/787186/12438

Comment: @Navin Under certain conditions, your answer may not be acceptable because it probably doesn't make things simpler.  Given $\cos(1)=a$, write me a formula that solves for $\cos(4.78)$ in terms of $a$.  It is not easily done, if it is doable, in your method.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but I suppose this works:
$$\cos ab=Re[(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))^a]$$

You can get the above equation by taking the real part of de Moivre's formula:
$$\cos n\theta +i\sin n\theta=(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n \,$$

Comment: Expression with real part is correct only for real argument. For complex case you need $\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$.

Answer (score 2):

For general $a$ and $b$, we cannot write $\cos (ab)$ in terms of the trig functions $\cos a,\sin a, \cos b, \sin b$. This is because the trig functions are periodic with period $2\pi$, so adding $2\pi$ to $b$ does not change any of these functions. But adding $2\pi$ to $b$ can change $\cos (ab)$ - for instance, if $a=1/2$, if sends $\cos (ab)$ to $-\cos(ab)$. Only if $a$ is an integer can we avoid this problem.

Comment: Did you ever hear about [multivalued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)?

Answer (score 2):

As many experts already noted here, an argument of cos(⋯) is an angle, and a sensible mathematical structure on angles is the one of [abelian-groups](/questions/tagged/abelian-groups) under “+”. We can add and subtract angles, as well as multiply them by integers. To some extent we can multiply angles by rational numbers, i.e. solve equations like
$$ qx = pa,\quad x,a\text{ are angles, }\ p,q\in{\mathbb Z},\ q≠0.$$
If $a$ is specified modulo 2π radians, then such solutions, placed on the trigonometric circle, will form a set of $q$ elements (vertices of a regular $q$-gon), that can be described with an algebraic equation.

There is no “reasonable” multiplication of an angle and an irrational number $t$. If $a$ is specified modulo 2π radians (that is a typical condition), then possible values of $ta$ will form a dense subset of the trigonometric circle, and hence values of trigonometric functions on it will have no use for calculations.

### Conclusion

**There are** trigonometric identities for products of an angle and a rational number; see other answers and [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-angle_formula) for some partial cases.

There are **no products of an angle and an irrational number**, as well as there are **no products of two angles**.

Answer (score 0):

One can use binomial expansion in combination with the complex extension of trig functions:

$$\cos(xy)=\frac{e^{xyi}+e^{-xyi}}{2}=\frac{a^{xy}+a^{-xy}}2$$

Using $a=e^i$ for simplicity.

We also have:

$$(a+a^{-1})^n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!a^{n-i}a^{-i}}{i!(n-i)!}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!a^{n-2i}}{i!(n-2i)!}$$

Which is obtained by binomial expansion.

We also have:

$$(a+a^{-1})^n=(a^{-1}+a)^n=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!a^{2j-n}}{j!(n-j)!}$$

And, combining the two, we get:

$$(a+a^{-1})^n=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!a^{n-2i}}{i!(n-i)!}+\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!a^{2j-n}}{j!(n-j)!}}2=\frac12\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}(a^{n-2i}+a^{-(n-2i)})$$

If we have $\cos(n)=\frac{a^n+a^{-n}}2$, then we have

$$(2\cos(n))^k=(a^n+a^{-n})^k=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\frac{a^{n(k-2i)}+a^{-n(k-2i)}}2$$

Furthermore, the far right of the last equation can be simplified back into the form of cosine:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\frac{a^{n(k-i)}+a^{-n(k-i)}}2=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}(\cos(n(k-2i)))$$

Thus, we can see that for $\cos(ny)$, it simply the first of the many terms in $\cos^n(y)$ and we may rewrite the summation formula as:

$$(2\cos(n))^k=\cos(nk)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}(\cos(n(k-2i)))$$

And rearranging terms, we get:

$$\cos(nk)=2^k\cos^k(n)-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}(\cos(n(k-2i)))$$

This becomes explicit formulas for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$

I note that there is no way by which you may reduce the above formula without the knowledge that $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, it is quite difficult to produce the formulas for, per say, $\cos(10x)$ because as you proceed to do so, you will notice that it requires knowledge of $\cos(8x),\cos(6x),\cos(4x),\dots$, which you can eventually solve, starting with $\cos(2x)$ (it comes out to be the well known double angle formula), using this to find, $\cos(4x)$, use that to find $\cos(6x)$, etc. all the way to $\cos(10x)$.

Notably, this can be easier than Chebyshev Polynomials because it only requires that you know the odd/even formulas less than the one you are trying to solve. (due to $-2i$)

But this is the closest I may give to you for the formula of $\cos(xy)$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

It is also true for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$.